# Split dataframe based on row value (python)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset similar to this:

| DATE | RETURN |
| --- | --- |
| 2000-1 | 0,1 |
| 2000-2 | 0,5 |
| 2000-3 | 0,1 |
| 2000-4 | 0,5 |
| value | Nan |
| 2000 | 0,5 |
| 2001 | 0,1 |
| 2002 | 0,5 |

How I can drop all rows after "value"? There are dates with a month at first and then comes this "value" and after that annual dates.

Edit:
Apparently, my table doesn't work so here:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[20001, 0.1], [20002, 0.6], [20003, 0.7],[20004, 0.5],[20005, 0.1],["value", ],[2000, 0.4], [2001, 0.5], [2002, 0.4]], columns=["DATE", "Return"])
```

Thanks for helping!

Comment: Generally you **don't** want to split a dataframe into two dataframes. Better to use to groupby() or else just figure out the indices of your two subsets. You can get the integer row index of 'value' with `np.where(df['DATE'] == value)`

Comment: For some reason, this works with my example data but gives nothing with my real data. I have read it with pd.read_csv

Answer (score 0):

You can use `idxmax`:

```
idx = df.DATE.eq("value").idxmax()                                                                                                                                                                        
df_pre, df_post = df.iloc[:idx], df.iloc[idx + 1:]
```

Output:

```
In [94]: df_pre                                                                                                                                                                                                    
Out[94]: 
      DATE RETURN
0  2000-1     0,1
1  2000-2     0,5
2  2000-3     0,1
3  2000-4     0,5

In [95]: df_post                                                                                                                                                                                                   
Out[95]: 
    DATE RETURN
5  2000     0,5
6  2001     0,1
7  2002     0,5
```

Comment: Sama problem with this than above. For some reason, this works with my example data but gives nothing with my real data. I have read it with pd.read_csv